# Return list with most common values in Python

Tags: python

For example:-

```
list1 = ['1','2','3']
list2 = ['2','3','4']
list3 = ['4','5','6']
```

I want to return `list1` and `list2` because they have the most values in common.

Comment: will you always have 3 lists?

Comment: list2 and list3 also have 2 values in common.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way would be to go through them and give them a score based on how many are in each list and return the two highest ranking ones. Make sure you code it in a way that's scalable and works for different lists. But I'm not really sure what this would be useful for.